# Change libtool used in command line

Tags: macos, terminal

I followed [this post](http://munchpress.com/installing-autoconf-automake-libtool-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion/) to install automake, autoconf and libtool.

When I check automake and autoconf versions they look fine. However, when I check libtool's version I get the following

```
$ libtool --version
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --version
```

however if I run libtool from install folder I get

```
$ /usr/local/libtool/bin/libtool --version
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2 Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996
```

So I think there is a version of libtool already installed with OS X. Is there a way to change it so that when I execute libtool it calls the one on `/usr/local/libtool/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your $PATH is different than normal, you could solve that with a sym link of the tool you want.

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then if the libtool you want to run first is `/usr/local/libtool/bin/libtool` then a quick

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/libtool/bin/libtool /usr/local/bin
```

At that point, you might have to restart your shell or rehash or `hash -r` in bash to get the `libtool` from `/usr/local/bin` to be preferred.